# How can I show the relationship based SQL Server table value in label in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have more than two SQL Server tables which have relationships. But when I want to show two columns in label it gives me an error. I want to show `Aurthorname` and `Catagoryname` where book id is equal to `textbox.text`:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SWEETHOME\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand coo = new SqlCommand("Select Book.BookId , Book.Booktitle, "+ 
                         "Aurthor.Aurthorname, Catagory.Catagoryname, Status.Status, "+
                         "Book.IssuingDate, Book.ReceivingDate, Book.Issuedby " + 
                         "From  Aurthor INNER JOIN Book ON Aurthor.Aurthorid = Book.Aurthorid "+
                         "INNER JOIN Catagory ON Book.Catagoryid = Catagory.Catagoryid INNER " +
                         "JOIN Status ON Book.Statusid = Status.Statusid Where Book.Bookid = '" +
                         textBox2.Text + "'", con);
SqlDataReader koo = coo.ExecuteReader();

while (koo.Read())
{
    label20.Text = koo["Aurthor.Aurthorname"].ToString();
    label21.Text = koo["Catagoryname.Catagory"].ToString();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a terrible naming strategy!

Comment: @adarshr I agree, but giving benefit of the doubt... perhaps the redundant addition of table names in column names was to assist working around the name qualification issue that the OP was asking about?

Comment: It's spelled **Author** (not "aurthor") and it's a **Category** (not a "catagory") - I left those wrong spellings in your code - but I'd recommend fixing those!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to prefix the column name with the tablename.
Just use

```
label20.Text = koo["Aurthorname"].ToString();
label21.Text = koo["CatagoryName"].ToString();
```

By the way, you have switched the tablename with the column name for the "Category" field

Comment: Hi @Steve, but do you know what happens when a specific field name exists in two tables? How would it be qualified then?  I can't find an answer to this at [SqlDataReader.Item Property @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy.aspx)

Comment: @Sepster Never let that happen, in these cases you need to change your source query appending an AS newfieldname to avoid any kind of ambiguity. However, a little test with linqpad shows that an automatic progressive counter is added to the problematic column (i.e field, field1, field2)

Comment: @Steve of course that'll work (I couldn't see the forest for the trees)!  Thanks for adding that, good tip for future readers (and me!)